# DiskImageMounter cannot open .dmg files on OS X Lion

Tags: router, modem

On os x Lion (10.7.1), DiskImageMounter is the program used to open dmg files so that the user  can install new programs. When I try to open images on my system attached to my home network they do not open. When I connect to the tethered network from my cell phone I can open them using the mac utility. What is wrong with my router and/or modem? I have a netgear router and and arris modem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I had to power-cycle my cable modem which was delivering a few bad packets to my terminal over wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an alias pointing to a remote copy of the image, but do not have a local copy of the image.  If your local network cannot reach the host that has a copy of the image, but your phone can, it would seem your ISP is experiencing problems.  Please note that stack overflow is a programming Q & A site and is not designed to answer general tech support questions.